# C# WCF Server retrieves 'List<T>' with 1 entry, but client doesn't receive it

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, wcf, endpoints

I am trying to retrieve a list of clients from the server (server using fluentNHibernate).
The client object is as follows:

```
[DataContract]
//[KnownType(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<ContactPerson>))]
//[KnownType(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<Address>))]
//[KnownType(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<BatchRequest>))]
//[KnownType(typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<Discount>))]
[KnownType(typeof(EClientType))]
[KnownType(typeof(EComType))]
public class Client
{
    #region Properties

[DataMember]
public virtual int ClientID { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public virtual EClientType ClientType { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public virtual string RegisterID {get; set;}

[DataMember]
public virtual string HerdCode { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public virtual string CompanyName { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public virtual bool InvoicePerBatch { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public virtual EComType ResultsComType { get; set; }

[DataMember]
public virtual EComType InvoiceComType { get; set; }



//[DataMember]
//public virtual IList<ContactPerson> Contacts { get; set; }

//[DataMember]
//public virtual IList<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

//[DataMember]
//public virtual IList<BatchRequest> Batches { get; set; }

//[DataMember]
//public virtual IList<Discount> Discounts { get; set; }

#endregion

#region Overrides

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    var other = obj as Client;
    if (other == null)
        return false;
    return other.GetHashCode() == this.GetHashCode();
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return ClientID.GetHashCode() | ClientType.GetHashCode() | RegisterID.GetHashCode() |
            HerdCode.GetHashCode() | CompanyName.GetHashCode() | InvoicePerBatch.GetHashCode() |
            ResultsComType.GetHashCode() | InvoiceComType.GetHashCode();// | Contacts.GetHashCode() |
            //Addresses.GetHashCode() | Batches.GetHashCode() | Discounts.GetHashCode();
}

#endregion
}
```

I have already tried to remove the sub-lists, though even with this simplified version of the client I still run into the problem.

My fluent mapping is:

```
public class ClientMap : ClassMap<Client>
    {
        public ClientMap()
        {
            Table("Clients");
            Id(p => p.ClientID);

            Map(p => p.ClientType).CustomType<EClientType>(); ;
            Map(p => p.RegisterID);
            Map(p => p.HerdCode);
            Map(p => p.CompanyName);
            Map(p => p.InvoicePerBatch);
            Map(p => p.ResultsComType).CustomType<EComType>();
            Map(p => p.InvoiceComType).CustomType<EComType>();

            //HasMany<ContactPerson>(p => p.Contacts)
            //    .KeyColumns.Add("ContactPersonID")
            //    .Inverse()
            //    .Cascade.All();

            //HasMany<Address>(p => p.Addresses)
            //    .KeyColumns.Add("AddressID")
            //    .Inverse()
            //    .Cascade.All();

            //HasMany<BatchRequest>(p => p.Batches)
            //    .KeyColumns.Add("BatchID")
            //    .Inverse()
            //    .Cascade.All();

            //HasMany<Discount>(p => p.Discounts)
            //    .KeyColumns.Add("DiscountID")
            //    .Inverse()
            //    .Cascade.All();

        }
```

The client method, seen below, connects to the server. The server retrieves the list, and everything *looks* right in the object, still, when it returns, the client doesn't receive anything (it receive a List object, but with nothing in it.

Herewith the calling method:

```
public List<s.Client> GetClientList()
        {
            try
            {
                s.DataServiceClient svcClient = new s.DataServiceClient();
                svcClient.Open();

                List<s.Client> clients = new List<s.Client>();

                clients = svcClient.GetClientList().ToList<s.Client>();

                svcClient.Close(); //when receiving focus from server, the clients object has a count of 0

                return clients;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }
            return null;
        }
```

and the server method:

```
public IList<Client> GetClientList()
        {
            var clients = new List<Client>();

            try
            {
                using (var session = SessionHelper.OpenSession())
                {
                    clients = session.Linq<Client>().Where(p => p.ClientID > 0).ToList<Client>();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry("eCOWS.Data", e.Message);
            }

            return clients; //returns a list with 1 client in it
        }
```

The server method interface is:

```
 [UseNetDataContractSerializer]
        [OperationContract]
        IList<Client> GetClientList();
```

For final reference, here are my client app.config entries:

```
 <system.serviceModel>

        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IDataService" listenBacklog="10" maxConnections="10"
                         transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                         receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
                      <readerQuotas maxDepth="51200000" maxStringContentLength="51200000" 
                                    maxArrayLength="51200000" maxBytesPerRead="51200000" 
                                    maxNameTableCharCount="51200000" />
                  <security mode="Transport"/>
                </binding>
            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>

        <client>
            <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9000/eCOWS/DataService"
                binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IDataService"
                contract="eCowsDataService.IDataService" name="NetTcpBinding_IDataService"
                behaviorConfiguration="eCowsEndpointBehavior">
            </endpoint>

           <endpoint address="MEX"
                     binding="mexHttpBinding"
                     contract="IMetadataExchange" />

        </client>

        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="eCowsEndpointBehavior">
              <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>

    </system.serviceModel>
```

and my server app.config:

```
    <system.serviceModel>

      <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
          <binding name="netTcpBinding"
                   maxConnections="10" listenBacklog="10"
                   transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions" 
                   maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                   sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="51200000" maxStringContentLength="51200000" 
                          maxArrayLength="51200000" maxBytesPerRead="51200000" 
                          maxNameTableCharCount="51200000" />
            <security mode="Transport"/>
          </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
      </bindings>

      <services>
      <service name="eCows.Data.Services.DataService" behaviorConfiguration="eCowsServiceBehavior">

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9001/eCOWS/" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9000/eCOWS/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <endpoint address="DataService" 
                  binding="netTcpBinding" 
                  contract="eCows.Data.Services.IDataService"
                  behaviorConfiguration="eCowsEndpointBehaviour">
        </endpoint>

        <endpoint address="MEX"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="eCowsEndpointBehaviour">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>      
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="eCowsServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10" maxConcurrentSessions="10"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="MexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>
```

I use to run into "socket closed / network or timeout" errors, and the trace showed clearly that on the callback it was looking for a listening endpoint, but couldn't find one.  Anyway, after adding the UseNetSerializer that error went away, yet now I'm just not getting anything.

PS. If I add all the commented out List items, I still retrieve an entry from the DB, but also still not receive anything on the client.

If I remove the  [UseNetDataContractSerializer] I get the following error(s) in the svclog:

> WARNING: Description  Faulted
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerSessionPreambleConnectionReader+ServerFramingDuplexSessionChannel
>
> WARNING: Description  Faulted
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel
>
> ERROR:
>   Initializing[eCows.Data.Models.Client#3]-failed
>   to lazily initialize a collection of
>   role:
>   eCows.Data.Models.Client.Addresses, no
>   session or session was closed
>
> ...
>
> ERROR: Could not find default
>   endpoint element that references
>   contract 'ILogbookManager' in the
>   ServiceModel client configuration
>   section. This might be because no
>   configuration file was found for your
>   application, or because no endpoint
>   element matching this contract could
>   be found in the client element.

If I add a .Not.LazyLoad to the List mapping items, I'm back at not receiving errors, but also not receiving any client information.

Comment: Are you saying that the client side call of svcClient.GetClientList() returns no items? Or, are you saying that the clients variable after the  clients = svcClient.GetClientList().ToList<s.Client>(); line has no items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WCF you need to use concrete types not interfaces.  Start off by using `List<Client>` instead of `IList<Client>`, or use simple arrays `Client[]`.  (It is possible to use interfaces, but thats a lot more work.)

The actual problem here is that Linq returns an runtime type that you can't specify in your data contract.

Sample copy of your server method:

```
public Client[] GetClientList()
{
    try
    {
        using (var session = SessionHelper.OpenSession())
        {
            return session.Linq<Client>().Where(p => p.ClientID > 0).ToArray<Client>();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry("eCOWS.Data", e.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: HI Chilltemp, 
Thanks for your reply, I think it worked, not entirely sure though since I am now getting an error relating to an endpoint for iLogbookManager (perhpas got to do with ServiceModelEx.dll ?)

I'm trying to find a solution for this endpoint issue, afterwhich I'll be able to know if your solution fixed my problem, since at the moment I am getting a connection drop everytime.

Comment: Any luck?  You don't have ILogbookManager listed in the config sample you provided.  The service's config file needs to list all endpoints implemented by the host class you are instantiating as a WCF service.

Comment: Well what a major delay in getting back to you on this!  Such is the process of moving overseas I guess :)

I can remember your comment helping me out a lot, and indeed fixed a certain section of my communication.  Thanks for the assist and sorry for the late reply.